# Simplifying if-then-else in summations or products

Tags: isabelle, isar

While doing some basic algebra, I frequently arrive at a subgoal of the following type (sometimes with a finite sum, sometimes with a finite product).

```
lemma foo:
  fixes N :: nat
  fixes a :: "nat ⇒ nat"
  shows "(a 0) = (∑x = 0..N. (if x = 0 then 1 else 0) * (a x))"
```

This seems pretty obvious to me, but neither `auto` nor `auto cong: sum.cong split: if_splits` can handle this. What's more, `sledgehammer` also surrenders when called on this lemma. How can one efficiently work with finite sums and products containing `if-then-else` in general, and how to approach this case in particular?

Comment: In that case "by (auto cong: if_cong simp: if_distrib[of ‹λx. x * a _› ‹_ = 0›])". By "find_thm" I knew I wanted to use "sum.delta". After that I tried to get the sum in the right form using auto (and an Isar proof). Finally I could compress the proof in one step... But I believe @Manuel Eberl can give a much better answer.

Comment: ... During the compression, I discovered that sum.delta is applied automatically. Therefore, it does not appear in the auto call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favourite way to do these things (because it is very general) is to use the rules `sum.mono_neutral_left` and `sum.mono_neutral_cong_left` and the corresponding `right` versions (and analogously for products). The rule `sum.mono_neutral_right` lets you drop arbitrarily many summands if they are all zero:

```
finite T ⟹ S ⊆ T ⟹ ∀i∈T - S. g i = 0
⟹ sum g T = sum g S
```

The `cong` rule additionally allows you to modify the summation function on the now smaller set:

```
finite T ⟹ S ⊆ T ⟹ ∀i∈T - S. g i = 0 ⟹ (⋀x. x ∈ S ⟹ g x = h x)
⟹ sum g T = sum h S
```

With those, it looks like this:

```
lemma foo:
  fixes N :: nat and a :: "nat ⇒ nat"
  shows "a 0 = (∑x = 0..N. (if x = 0 then 1 else 0) * a x)"
proof -
  have "(∑x = 0..N. (if x = 0 then 1 else 0) * a x) = (∑x ∈ {0}. a x)"
    by (intro sum.mono_neutral_cong_right) auto
  also have "… = a 0"
    by simp
  finally show ?thesis ..
qed
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the left-hand side could use an arbitrary value between `0` and `N`, what about adding a more general lemma

```
lemma bar:
  fixes N :: nat
  fixes a :: "nat ⇒ nat"
  assumes
    "M ≤ N"
  shows "a M = (∑x = 0..N. (if x = M then 1 else 0) * (a x))"
  using assms by (induction N) force+
```

and solving the original one with `using bar by blast`?

Comment: So that just means that force can solve the lemma foo, because foo is the base case needed to prove bar by induction?

Comment: @1Darco1 Not quite: the induction is done on the size of the set, not on its elements. The original lemma `foo` can be proved with `by (induction N) simp_all`, but I thought you are looking for a more general solution where an arbitrary element of the set can be used.